# how to add % sign to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble adding the % sign to a ggplot (R) (to the line chart)

here is my plot code:

```
ggplot(table)  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=year, y=order_cnt_in_thousends),stat="identity", fill="tan1", colour="sienna3")+
    geom_line(aes(x=year, y=yearly_change ),stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=yearly_change, x=year, y=yearly_change), colour="black")+
    geom_text(aes(label=order_cnt_in_thousends, x=year, y=order_cnt_in_thousends), colour="black", vjust = -0.5) +   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year")
```

Iv'e tried to add this to the column:
`table$yearly_change <-paste(year_growth_table$yearly_change, "%")` but now I have problem since it's discrete and not continuous.

[image: plot image]

Comment: in the aesthetics of the first `geom_text`: `label = scales::percent(yearly_change / 100, accuracy = 1.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paste` function inside the `aes()` to make it a string with "%" :

```
set.seed(1234)
df = data.frame(year=as.Date(c("2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2018-01-01")),order_cnt_in_thousends = sample(1000,3),yearly_change = sample(1000,3))

ggplot(df)  + 
geom_bar(aes(x=year, y=order_cnt_in_thousends),stat="identity", fill="tan1", colour="sienna3")+
geom_line(aes(x=year, y=yearly_change ))+
geom_text(aes(label=paste(yearly_change,"%"), x=year, y=yearly_change), colour="black")+
geom_text(aes(label=order_cnt_in_thousends, x=year, y=order_cnt_in_thousends), colour="black", vjust = -0.5) +   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year")
```

[image]